# How can I output different names using IF and LEFT function on Excel with the same initials?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
IF(LEFT(A1;3)="SHE";"Emergency shower";IF(LEFT(A1;2)="SH"; "Shower")
```

It always returns "Shower" since it reads the first two letters, where the condition is true. How can I code in a way that it reads the first 2 letters, but validating that it has 3, it displays the " emergency shower" ?

I have tried OR and AND funtions but it hasn't worked

Comment: The way it is written if A1 is `Sheet` it will return `"Emergency shower"` and not even test the two character.  For something like this you test the longest strings to the shortest strings.  IF will short circuit on the first TRUE.

Comment: Sample data and the expected result might be helpful here.

Comment: What language are you writing in?  The syntax isn't quite right for either VBA or an Excel formula.

Comment: what do you mean by sample data? I expect it to output the right word according to what it reads " SHE" or "SH"

Comment: `=IF(LEFT(A1;3)="SHE";"Emergency shower";IF(LEFT(A1;2)="SH"; "Shower";"neither"))` should do that.  If the first three are `SHE` it will never test for the the `SH`.

Comment: is "neither" a function or is it just gonna display the word "neither"?

Comment: @vsegrini it is the false if neither of the test return true.